# What is "serialized relocation" in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, serialization, shuffle

I have learned about shuffle in Spark.

In Spark,if you want to use unsafeshufflewriter,the records must support "serialized relocaton".

I know of object serialized in java is for class information transmission in net. 
But I don't know what "serialized relocation" is; how can I use it? And how does Spark use it?

Comment: https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=issues@spark.apache.org&q=subject:%22%5C%5Bjira%5C%5D+%5C%5BCommented%5C%5D+%5C%28SPARK%5C-7081%5C%29+Faster+sort%5C-based+shuffle+path+using+binary+processing+cache%5C-aware+sort%22&o=newest&f=1  Technical stuff, but this gives an idea

Comment: This may also help you: https://www.slideshare.net/bobyangbo/spark-shuffle-deep-dive-how-shuffle-works-in-spark